# Using Javascript to calculate form fields -- get NaN as a result

Tags: javascript, forms, calculator, nan

I have created a short form that is supposed to calculate values based on user input.  I've got most of it figured out but can't seem to get the results to show up in the totals field.  Instead, I get NaN.

I'm trying to use parseInt but haven't had any luck yet.

Here is what I have so far:

The Javascript:

```
 var AdPrice = document.getElementsByTagName('input') = 0;
  var ColorCharge = document.getElementsByTagName('input') = 0;
  var WebAd = document.getElementsByTagName('input') = 0;
  var AdSubtotal = 0;
  var DownPayment = document.getElementsByTagName('input') = 0;
  var TotalPrice = 0;
  var Payments = document.getElementsByTagName('input') = 0;
  var TotalPayment = 0; 

function updateTotal()
{
  var subtotal = AdPrice + ColorCharge + WebAd;
  var total = subtotal - DownPayment;
  var totalmonthlypayment = total / Payments;

 parseFloat(document.getElementById('AdSubtotal').value = subtotal);
 parseFloat(document.getElementById('TotalPrice').value = total);
 parseFloat(document.getElementById('Payment').value = totalmonthlypayment);


}
```

The HTML:

```
<fieldset>
              <legend>Payment Details</legend>

             Ad Charge $

              <input type="text" name="AdPrice" id="AdPrice" class="medium" onChange="updateTotal()" /><br />

              Color Charge +

              <input type="text" name="ColorCharge" id="ColorCharge" class="medium" onChange="updateTotal()" /><br />

              Web Ad +
              <input type="text" name="WebAd" id="WebAd" class="medium" onChange="updateTotal()" /><br />

              Subtotal =

              <input type="text" name="AdSubtotal" id="AdSubtotal" readonly class="medium"  /><br />

           Down Payment -

           <input type="text" name="DownPayment" id="DownPayment" class="medium" onChange="updateTotal()" /><br />

           Total = 
           <input type="text" name="TotalPrice" id="TotalPrice" readonly class="medium"  /><br /><br />



           # Consec. Payments \

             <input type="text" name="Payments" id="Payments" class="medium" onChange="updateTotal" /><br />

            Amt Each Payment $ 

            <input type="text" name="Payment" id="Payment" class="medium" readonly  /><br /><br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="ProratedCheck" id="ProratedCheck" /> <span style="margin-right:10px;">Prorated/Length</span><input type="text" name="ProratedLength" id="ProratedLength" />
</fieldset>
```

I also have a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kjetterman/eHQV4/10/

Comment: nothing personal, but you need to read a guide on how to create forms, cause none of this works the way it should.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: You should not be using getElementsByTagName to get a single input as this gets ALL input tags, not just the one you want. It would be useful to read up a little on jQuery to help you get the form elements you want to calculate.

Comment: You need to learn basic Javascript. What are statements like `var AdPrice = document.getElementsByTagName('input') = 0;` supposed to do? What do you think you're assigning 0 to?

Comment: Didn't you notice the errors in the Javascript console "ReferenceError: Left side of assignment is not a reference."?

Comment: @EliteOctagon This is not the entire form, just a small snippet of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several errors on the javascript that you need to work on, as mentioned on the comments for your question you should use `getElementById` for retrieving DOM elements, other issue you had is that your code was running as soon as the browser gets the response which at the moment might not have the DOM ready for work so all your references were coming back as NULL. Here's the working version, you still need to add some validation for when the initial values are zeroes so you don't get NaN as result of operations.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wy7kE/2/

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I was looking for.  Initially I was looking at different methods of doing this and trying to apply what I thought would work logically.  As you can tell by my code I am fairly new to this.  I appreciate you taking the time to look at it!! :)

Comment: I have it working!  I decided to re-write it in jQuery.  You helped me solve the main issue which was how to use parseFloat.  Here is the fiddle:  <http://jsfiddle.net/kjetterman/2XLcK/8/>

Answer (score 1):

Division by zero (subtotal) at the beginning.

And: 
Does this kind of binding work? I think not. Very new to me.......

What about placing the "getElements"-lines inside the method?